# Terraform - A reference to a resource type error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Error below keeps happening. I have played around with various configurations inside this subnets_map construct and no luck. Clearly missing some fundamental aspect here. Thanks.

```
Waiting for the plan to start...

Terraform v1.1.2
on linux_amd64
Configuring remote state backend...
Initializing Terraform configuration...
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│
│   on Modules/privateendpoints/main.tf line 36, in locals:
│   36:       for subnets in pe_subnet : {
│
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
│ access, specifying the resource name.
```

**Variables**

```
variable "private_endpoints" {
  type = map(object({
    name                = string
    resource_group_name = string
    pe_subnet = map(object({
      name                 = string
      virtual_network_name = string
      resource_group_name  = string
    }))
    subresource_name               = list(string) # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource
    is_manual_connection           = bool
    request_message                = string # 140 character limit
    dns_zone_names                 = list(string)
    dns_zone_group_name            = string
    private_connection_resource_id = string
    tags                           = map(string)
  }))
  description = "Map containing Private Endpoint and Private DNS Zone details"
  default     = {}
}
```

**Part of MAIN**

```
  subnets_map = distinct(flatten([
    for pesubnet_k, pesubnet_v in var.private_endpoints : [
      for subnets in pe_subnet : {
        pesubnet_key         = pesubnet_k
        name                 = pesubnet_v.name
        virtual_network_name = pesubnet_v.virtual_network_name
        resource_group_name  = pesubnet_v.resource_group_name
    }]
  ]))
}
```

**TFVARS**

```
private_endpoints = {
  pe1 = {
    name                = "pe-kv-eastus2-01"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    pe_subnet = {
      name                 = "pe-snet-eastus2-01" # name of the private endpoint subnet
      virtual_network_name = "vnet-eastus2-01"    # name of the vnet the private endpoint subnet is in
      resource_group_name  = "Terraform1"         # rg name of the vnet
    }
    subresource_name               = ["vault"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
    request_message                = null
    dns_zone_names                 = ["privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net"]
    dns_zone_group_name            = "keyvault_dns"
    private_connection_resource_id = "/subscriptions/xxxyyy/resourceGroups/Terraform1/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kv-eastus2-01"
    tags = {
      pe = "KeyVault"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` expression you've declared two local symbols `pesubnet_k` and `pesubnet_v`, representing the key and value respectively from each element of `var.private_endpoints`.

That doesn't declare any symbol named just `pe_subnet`, and so Terraform assumes that you are trying to access a resource declared using a `resource "pe_subnet" "..."` block, which is the default interpretation of any reference that doesn't have a special prefix at the start and doesn't refer to a locally-defined symbol.

I assume your goal here was to refer to the `pe_subnet` attribute of each of your endpoint objects. The good news is that I don't think you actually need that second level of `for` expression here, because that attribute is just a single object, rather than a collection of objects:

```
  subnets_map = [
    for pesubnet_k, pesubnet_v in var.private_endpoints : {
        pesubnet_key         = pesubnet_k
        name                 = pesubnet_v.pesubnet.name
        virtual_network_name = pesubnet_v.pesubnet.virtual_network_name
        resource_group_name  = pesubnet_v.pesubnet.resource_group_name
    }
  ]
```

Because `pesubnet_v` represents each of the direct values of `var.private_endpoints`, a reference like `pesubnet_v.pesubnet` refers to the `pesubnet` attribute of each one. There's no need for `flatten` here because this data structure is already "flat" in terms of collections: there's only one `pe_subnet` object per element, even though those attributes are enclosed in a single nested object.

Comment: The resolved value of variable "private_endpoints" is not appropriate:
element "pe1": attribute "pe_subnet": element "virtual_network_name":
object required.

Comment: I was reading up on the flatten documentation and it specifically says it is for a list. flatten takes a list and replaces any elements that are lists with a flattened sequence of the list contents. I have seen references to maps as well somewhere, so would also like clarity on this. @martin-atkins